# derivative manipulation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was reading a book and was hoping to get clarification.
[here is the image from the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dELX2.png)
And here it is again:
$$ M{d^2x\over dt^2} = f(x)  $$
they claim can be written as
$${M \over 2}{d \over dx}\left({dx \over dt}\right)^2 = f(x)$$
**Is the factor $\frac 1 2$ incorrect?** I find:
$${M \over 2}{d \over dx}\left({dx \over dt}\right)^2 = {\frac M 2}{d \over dx}{dx \over dt}{dx \over dt} = {\frac M 2}{d \over dt}{dx \over dt}={\frac M 2}{d^2x \over dt^2}$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Maybe you should apply the product rule when differentiating $\dfrac {dx}{dt}\dfrac {dx}{dt}$ with respect to $x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y = \frac{dx}{dt} $.  This allows the arithmetic to go a bit more smoothly.

\begin{align*}
    \frac{M}{2} \frac{d}{dx} (y^2) &= \frac{M}{2} \left( 2y \frac{dy}{dx} \right)\\
    &= My\frac{dy}{dx}\\
    &= M \frac{dx}{dt} \frac{dy}{dx}\\
    &= M \frac{dy}{dt}\\
    &= M \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}
\end{align*}